# Postfix can not send to specific domain 'connection time out'

Tags: postfix

I am using postifix 2.11.3 on Debian 8.10. It works fine except for specific domain. For this Domain I can not send emails while I can for all others domains. In my log I see "Connection Timeout" and nothing more as a clue. There is an attachemnt to the mail but it is very small ~ 330kb. I have checked dkim and spf and they are both ok. I dont know where to look. Any help is apprecieted, below is an exerpt from my mail.log

```
    Jan 31 16:27:43 euve252220 postfix/smtpd[29306]: 0718F6049C4:   client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
    Jan 31 16:27:43 euve252220 postfix/cleanup[29284]: 0718F6049C4: message-id=<000a01d39a9f$9fc21290$df4637b0$@gr>
    Jan 31 16:27:43 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 16:27:43 euve252220 amavis[14588]: (14588-19) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [85.72.35.187]:50603 [85.72.35.187]  <info@lakre.gr> -> <tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, Queue-ID: 4F0846046C4, Message- ID: <000a01d39a9f$9fc21290$df4637b0$@gr>, mail_id: 8LtyFFyqOs-Y, Hits: 0.214, size: 333315, queued_as: 0718F6049C4, dkim_new=lakre:lakre.gr, 469 ms
    Jan 31 16:27:43 euve252220 postfix/smtp[29302]: 4F0846046C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=14, delays=13/0.02/0/0.47, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10027): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 0718F6049C4)
    Jan 31 16:28:13 euve252220 postfix/smtp[29307]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=30, delays=0.02/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
    Jan 31 16:33:19 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 16:33:49 euve252220 postfix/smtp[29982]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=367, delays=336/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
    Jan 31 16:43:19 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 16:43:49 euve252220 postfix/smtp[31510]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=967, delays=937/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
    Jan 31 17:03:20 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 17:03:50 euve252220 postfix/smtp[1477]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=2168, delays=2138/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
    Jan 31 17:43:21 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 17:43:51 euve252220 postfix/smtp[6492]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=4569, delays=4538/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
    Jan 31 18:53:22 euve252220 postfix/qmgr[1198]: 0718F6049C4: from=<info@lakre.gr>, size=334483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jan 31 18:53:52 euve252220 postfix/smtp[15112]: 0718F6049C4: to=<tsachalim@pireusbank.gr>, relay=none, delay=8769, delays=8739/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to pireusbank.gr[185.53.178.29]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain `pireusbank.gr` has no corresponding MX records, therefore emails cannot be sent to that domain.

This isn't the fault of your postfix configuration.

**Edit:** As @PeterGreen has mentioned, while MX records are not necessary for the delivery of mail, the server doesn't seem to be listening for TCP connections on port 25, confirming the idea that `pireusbank.gr` cannot recieve mail in its current configuration.

Comment: mx records aren't strictly vital for mail, though the combination of no mx records and a connection refused error does tend to indicate that the admin of the domain has not set things up for mail.

Answer (score 2):

I did some test myself. The problem is not on your server rather on "pireusbank.gr" mailserver (185.53.178.29).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the sender of the email, since `pireusbank.gr` appears to be misspelled `piraeusbank.gr` which does have proper MX records set:

```
piraeusbank.gr.     953 IN  MX  10 mail1.piraeusbank.gr.
piraeusbank.gr.     953 IN  MX  5 mail2.piraeusbank.gr.
piraeusbank.gr.     953 IN  MX  5 mail3.piraeusbank.gr.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on your server, you always try to send a test email to another public server like outlook or gmail before post and question on serverfault.